# Reset a the background and foreground colors of a group of Text to default colors

Tags: swiftui

I have a group of custom text element which when tapped on changes their background and foreground colors. I also have a reset button which when clicked should reset all custom elements to their default background and foreground color. However, my current attempt below doesn't quite do that yet. As the reset button uses a bool state value and there is no way to quietly toggle it to false after it has been clicked.

```
enum Categories: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case CategoryA, CategoryB, CategoryC
    var id: Self { self }
}

struct MyApp: View {
    @State private var reset = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
            HStack {
                Text("Categories")
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    reset.toggle()
                }){
                    Text("Reset")
                }
            }.padding()
            HStack(alignment: .center){
                ForEach(Categories.allCases){ item in
                    MyText(reset: $reset, label: item.rawValue)
                }
            }.padding()
        }.background(Color.gray)
        
    }
}

struct MyText: View {
    @State private var tapped = false
    private var bgCol: Color {
        if reset{
            return Color.white
        }else if tapped{
            return Color.blue
        }else{
            return Color.white
        }
    }
    private var fgCol: Color{
        if reset {
            return Color.blue
        } else if self.tapped {
            return Color.white
        } else {
            return Color.blue
        }
    }
    @Binding var reset: Bool
    var label: String
    
    var body : some View{
        Text(label)
            .padding()
            .background(self.bgCol)
            .foregroundColor(self.fgCol)
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.tapped.toggle()
                if reset {
                    reset.toggle()
                }
            }
    }
}

struct App_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyApp()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `onChange` callback to react to changes to the `reset` flag, instead of examining the actual value. So `MyText` can be simplified to the following (no changes needed to `MyApp`):

```swift
struct MyText: View {
    @State private var tapped = false
    @Binding var reset: Bool
    let label: String

    private var bgCol: Color {
        tapped ? .blue : .white
    }
    private var fgCol: Color {
        tapped ? .white : .blue
    }

    var body : some View {
        Text(label)
            .padding()
            .background(bgCol)
            .foregroundColor(fgCol)
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .onTapGesture {
                tapped.toggle()
            }
            .onChange(of: reset) { _ in
                tapped = false
            }
    }
}
```

---

*EDIT* Actually, `reset` doesn't even need to be passed as a `Binding`, because it's read-only.

So the `MyText` in this answer could be simplified further to begin like this:

```swift
@State private var tapped = false
let reset: Bool
let label: String
```

and the `ForEach` loop in `MyApp` changed to this:

```swift
ForEach(Categories.allCases){ item in
    MyText(reset: reset, label: item.rawValue)
}
```

Comment: I just tried that but the issue is `reset` has to be set back to `false` after all the MyText elements colors have been set to default colors. I added `reset = false` after `tapped = false` in the `onChange` callback. However, I'm not too confident if that is a good approach set `reset` to `false`.

Comment: Did you try it? Just replace ```MyText``` with the version in the answer, ```MyApp``` doesn't change. Every time ```reset``` is toggled then a reset happens, it doesn't matter what its actual value is.

Comment: I did try it. The point I was making in my comment was that after the Text colors have been set to the default color, `reset` has to be toggled back to `false`, so another click on the reset button initiates another reset.

Comment: @r360 With the code in the answer, a reset happens every time ```reset``` is toggled, the value itself doesn't matter. In other words, a reset happens when you toggle the flag from false -> true and another reset happens when you toggle it from true -> false. That is why, there is no need to set the value back to false. I'm surprised you didn't see this, if you tried it with the code provided.

Comment: I think I see why it didn't work without setting reset to false. All good now.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you should keep track of the "selected" states of the categories in `MyApp`, instead of in each `MyText`. To reset, simply set all the selected states to false.

```
// in MyApp
@State var tappedStates = Categories.allCases.map { ($0, false) }
```

Reset button:

```
Button("Reset") {
    tappedStates = Categories.allCases.map { ($0, false) }
}
```

`MyTest` could simply be:

```
struct MyText: View {
    @Binding var tapped: Bool
    private var bgCol: Color {
        tapped ? .blue : .white
    }
    private var fgCol: Color{
        !tapped ? .blue : .white
    }
    let label: String
    
    var body : some View{
        Text(label)
            .padding()
            .background(self.bgCol)
            .foregroundColor(self.fgCol)
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .onTapGesture {
                tapped.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

Here I am lazy, so I just used a tuple that holds the category value, and a `Bool` to indicate whether that category is selected. Consider making your own struct for this.

To reset, simply assign `Categories.allCases.map { ($0, false) }` to `tappedStates` again.

Then, pass a binding of this to `ForEach`, so that you can get a `Binding<Bool>` from each item to pass to `MyText`.

```
ForEach($tappedStates, id: \.0){ item in
    // item.1 here is a Binding<Bool>
    MyText(tapped: item.1, label: item.wrappedValue.0.rawValue)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however the reset did not work when I tried.

Comment: @r360 What do you mean by "did not work"? Can you describe what happened, and what should happen instead? My answer was indeed a bit unclear. See my edit and describe exactly what "did not work".

Comment: The reset did not work for me